# What happens to dataCollection state of Google analytics when firebase analytics are turned on from off?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

In my app I had Google analytics off with

```
        <meta-data
        android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated"
        android:value="false" />
```

However I had totally forgot about that, and I have showed the users a banner for granting or declining google analytics tracking and then setting the dataCollection accordingly

```
 firebaseAnalytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(userPref);
```

My question is, now tha I will set manifest to

```
        <meta-data
        android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated"
        android:value="false" />

        <meta-data android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled"
        android:value="false" />
```

will the users' permission be retained ? meaning if the user had accepted tracking (while analytics were permanently closed) will now be tracked? or should I question for their consent again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have tested it and apparently the state of

```
firebase_analytics_collection_enabled
```

is respected even with

```
   <meta-data
    android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated"
    android:value="false" />
```

I'm just posting it here just in case it helps someone in my position

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to [this](https://www.google.com/about/company/user-consent-policy-help) you have to ask consent only once. If you want your users to be able to revoke their consent - you have to create a possibility for them to make it explicitly - inform them how and where to do that. After the users have revoked their consent - you would have to ask them once more.

Thus if your users have already given their consent it works all the time for the scope you've described in a disclosure message. If you want to change the scope of features that require user consent - you have to ask for users' consent once more - but only for the new features.

Also, as far as I understand(I am not sure though - I haven't found definite info about that), consent works only for one installation though - after reinstalling the app, the disclosure should be shown once more for the user.

The data stored is persistent though - almost indefinitely.

Comment: The question is not about consent. In my case users have given consent but since I had forgotten firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated variable set to true, While the users had consented for analytics I had no analytics data. However as I answered above the data_collection variable is respected meaning that you don't have to show again the banner you just need to set the firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated to false and everything will work accordingly.

Comment: @Libathos I quote your question: `will the users' permission be retained ? meaning if the user had accepted tracking (while analytics were permanently closed) will now be tracked? or should I question for their consent again ?` You never ask about what happens to the data - you ask about the users' permissions, if the tracking will be enabled(obviously not), and whether you should ask once more for the consent - I have answered your questions. You have answered... something...